# Higher Order Partial Derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

If i have 3 times differential function $ z= f(x^3 / y^4) $ how can i get:

a) ${\partial z \over \partial x}$

b) ${ \partial ^2z \over  \partial x^2}$

c) ${\partial^2z \over \partial x \partial y}$

Comment: I really don't get your question. Also a) doesn't make any sense and take out the * in c). Bad notation.

Comment: I fixed it. Tnx. Btw what you don't get? I got that problem in math exam today, and didn't know how to do it.....

Comment: I also think they should be partial derivatives. No? I think it's all those typos that makes it hard to understand. Use "\partial" for $\partial$

Comment: just starting with TeX so tnx ;)

Comment: More understandable now! Do you know the chain rule for multivariate functions?

Comment: I know the formula....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you are grasping the notation.

A) Already answered.

B) This simply means that you are to take another derivative, again with respect to x -- note the use of the product rule:

$$\frac{ \partial ^2 z }{ \partial x^2} 
= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f_x(g)g_x
= f_{xx}(g)g_x + f_x(g)g_{xx}
= \ f_{xx}\left({x^3 \over y^4}\right) \frac{3x^2}{y^4}  + f_x\left({x^3 \over y^4}\right) \frac{6x}{y^4}.$$

C) This part asks you to take the derivative of z twice (hence the $\partial^2$), first with respect to y, then with respect to x (in operator form, the order is read from right to left; notice that for subscripts this order is reversed!).
$${\partial z \over \partial y} 
  = f_y(g)g_y 
  = f_y\left({x^3 \over y^4}\right){x^3 \over -4y^5},  $$

$${\partial^2 z \over \partial x \partial y} 
  = f_{yx}(g)g_y + f_{y}(g)g_{yx}  
  = f_{yx}\left({x^3 \over y^4}\right){-4x^3 \over y^5} + f_y\left({x^3 \over y^4}\right){-12x^2 \over y^5}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's some help for the first, which will hopefully help for the others:

We want to compute
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x^3/y^4)
$$

Since $y$ is held constant, we can use the chain rule:

$$
\frac{d}{dx} f(g(x)) = f'(g(x))g'(x)
$$

where in this case, $g(x) = x^3/y^4$, and hence $g'(x) = 3x^2/y^4$.

Hopefully this help!

Comment: Tnx man! It helps. Now I understand a.   Can you do b and c too?